# How to get BoundingBox after rotation, scale?

Tags: ios, scenekit

```
SCNVector3 min, max;
[self getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];
```

the returned min and max value  it's base on raw size

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the bounding box of the `parentNode` for the node's transform to be taken into account.

Comment: How can i do that? When i perform projectPoint to get 2D points after rotation i am getting weird result. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SCNVector3 min, max;
[self getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

SCNVector3 cMin = [self convertVector:min toNode:rootNode];
SCNVector3 cMax = [self convertVector:max toNode:rootNode];
```

Comment: Please provide comments with your code on how it solves the question.